# location of include file of elasticsearch for php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch in Ubuntu using apt-get as explained in:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html

Then I am trying to use elasticsearch in my php code which requires me to include file `vendor/autoload.php`. In the example elasticsearch is installed using composer. The example I am trying to follow is in this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xb1dHLg-Lk

I tried to located autoload.php in my elasticsearch installation folders but it does not exist there.

So I am struck on how to proceed with elasticsearch in php if I have installed it using apt-get?
Do I need to again install it using composer as explained in the video around 3 min?

Comment: I made the links friendlier to the eye and clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php elasticsearch has to use composure to setup index as far as I know.